# How to wrap a existing mobile site to native app

Tags: python, mobile, cordova

Our team current build a mobile site with python server language run on browser. Now we want to extend some functionalities such as calendar syncing and push notifications so we plan to wrap our existing mobile site with phonegap framework.

My question is whether that solution is possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to write an app in Html+CSS+JavaScript, but notice that the app will be a client consuming data from a server (JSON, XML, etc.). In other words, the server won't build the layout, but will provide the info to the client.
In conclusion, with tools like PhoneGap you'll be able to take advantage of the design you already have, although a native app is a completely different concept from a website, not just a wrapper.